# Why is exception not caught?

Tags: c#, exception, nullreferenceexception

The following code generates a `NullReferenceException`, but is not caught by the try block (in both `Debug` and `Release` mode):

```
using System;

namespace ExceptionTest {
    public class Program {
        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            String text = null;
            try {
                if (text.Equals("t1")) {
                    Console.WriteLine("r1");
                } else {
                    Console.WriteLine("r2");
                }
            } catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception catched!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Instead the program breaks and the offending line is highlighted:

[image]

**Why?**

Update: Textual representation of the exception as suggested by Scott:

```
System.NullReferenceException occurred
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=ExceptionTest
```

Comment: You *probably* have your debugger configured to break on first-chance exceptions. If you run this without a debugger attached, does it print "Exception catched"?

Comment: also have you tried using `==` if I am not mistaken it throws exceptions differently than `string.Equals(string)`

Comment: It's generally bad practice to catch general Exceptions like that. It can lead to sparatic and untraceable behavior in your code. Not to mention exceptions are extremely non-performant. 

If a variable can be null, you should check for a null value before accessing it!

Comment: On the side note, you can also do this:
`if ("t1".Equals(text))`
It won't throw an exception. ;)

Comment: Thanks for the many suggestions! Sure, I basically know how exception handling works, but coming from the Java world, I was not aware of the concept of "first-chance-exceptions". But I now read a short article about it and got the idea. The example above is held deliberately very basic to show up the issue I was confronted with. Thanks.

Comment: @vcsjones: No, it also stopped when running in `Release` mode without debugger attached. Thanks for refering to the concept of "first-chance exceptions". I wasn't aware of this concept, but now read a short article about it.

Comment: Another tip for when you are posting, click the "[copy exception detail to the clipboard](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saraford/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276/)" and use that when you need to post a question here that has a exception in it. It was good that you included a text copy of the code, but it would have been better to have a text copy of the exception too.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Okay I understand, it's better for the search engines :) I updated my question and will do it like this for future posts. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the example image under Exception settings: turn of the checkbox.

By doing this it will not break when a null reference exception is thrown.And the catch would catch the Exception.

Comment: I selected this answer as the correct one, because it was the first one that pinpointed the solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It happens because you have this box checked

[image]

That makes your debugger break before it gets to the catch block, if you hit continue you would see it continue in to the catch. If you uncheck the box you can re-enable it under your "Exception Settings" window found via the `Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings` dropdown menu. The section "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" contains the `NullRefrenceException` option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Visual Studio 2015:

Debug->Windows->Exception Settings

Search for NullReferenceException, and uncheck that.